# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string in SP_whoisactive

Tags: sql-server-2014

When I run `sp_whoisactive` with `@get_transaction_info = 1`,
I am getting an error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_WhoIsActive, Line 3187 [Batch Start Line 1]
>
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I run it on SQL 2014 SP1

Comment: Maybe you could look into `sp_WhoIsActive` code on `Line 3187 `?

Comment: it tries to convert to datetime part of the string. I will change it to use try_convert